# Sintaxe criada dinamicamente

Tags: php, json

Tenho uma sintaxe (em php) para gerar o arquivo Json. Só que preciso que essa sintaxe seja criada dinamicamente, ou seja, de acordo com o resultado de outra classe.

Está assim:

Dados os valores de uma Matriz

```
Coluna 1  - Coluna 2

   190       340

   190       54
```

Sendo que, os dados da coluna 1. São os pais dos dados da coluna 2.
Na linha zero o valor (190) está sendo o pai do valor (340), e assim por diante.

Dado esses valores, a sintaxe ficaria assim:

```
$name = "name";
$children = "children";
$valor1 = "190";
$valor2 = "340";
$var = array ($name=>"$valor1",$children=>array(array($name=>"$valor2"),array($name=>"$ip1")));
$ip = json_encode($var, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Preciso que a sintaxe, que está entrando na variavel $var. Seja criada sozinha de acordo com minha matriz, com a quantidade de valores que ela tem.

Pois a matriz poderá (e terá) mais linhas.

Comment: Sua árvore possui apenas dois níveis, certo? (i.e. não dá pra `190` ser pai de `340` e `340` ser pai de `42`. Ou dá?) Em outras palavras, o número que aparece na primeira coluna estará sempre no nível 1, e o número que aparece na segunda estará sempre no nível 2, é isso mesmo? P.S. Por um acaso seu array está ordenado? Isso facilitaria bastante...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se sua matriz de entrada estiver ordenada, isso facilita bastante a operação, pois basta guardar em uma variável o último `array` criado e verificar se o pai da próxima linha é igual. Se for, acrescenta a coluna 2 nos seus filhos; se não for, cria um `array` novo. Exemplo:

```
$entrada = array(
    array(col_1=>190, col_2=>340),
    array(col_1=>190, col_2=>54),
    ...
);

$name = "name";
$children = "children";
$var = array(); # $var será um array (top level) cujos elementos são o pai e seus filhos
                # Se você quer algo diferente como a raiz da sua árvore, é necessário definir
                # o que.

asort($entrada); # Ordenar de modo que os valores da coluna 1 venham juntos

$ultimo = null;
foreach($entrada as $colunas) {
    # Cria um array novo se o último tiver um pai diferente
    if ( is_null($ultimo) || $ultimo[$name] != $colunas["col_1"] ) {
        if ( !is_null($ultimo) )
            array_push($var, $ultimo);
        $ultimo = array($name=>$colunas["col_1"], $children=>array());
    }
    # Adiciona o filho no pai
    $ultimo[$children][] = array($name => $colunas["col_2"]);
}
if ( !is_null($ultimo) )
    $var[] = $ultimo;

$ip = json_encode($var, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

[Exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/N9AilE). P.S. Tenho pouca experiência prática com PHP, então o código acima pode não ser a melhor forma de implementar, mas a lógica que quero passar é esta.